# Blogger main page doesn't show more than 12 posts

Tags: blogger

In my blog's main page I want all my posts to appear, I tried

**Settings --> Posts, Comments --> Show at most**
and I set 25 posts but not working It always show only 12 posts

How can I show all my posts in the main page of my blog?

Answer (score 1):

As a Blogger template developer, I have access to a lot of Blogger blogs and some of these blogs are facing this issue (it's a bug).

This issue happens to certain blogs, no matter if they're using the default Blogger or a custom Blogger template. That means this issue does not come from having a custom Blogger template.

Some of the blogs will work with huge value of `Show Post` (with a random limit). Sometimes it will work until 9 posts, 12 posts, 15 posts, 19 posts or more, but the most unfortunate is some of blogs only will work with 2 posts (max).

We, as bloggers and developers, can't fix this bug. Only the developers of Blogger itself can access their root file codes to fix this bug. So you maybe can contact Blogger via the Feedback button on "Blogger Dashboard."

Answer (score 1):

I just accidentally solve this problem. If you also facing this problem. Try to use the same method.

Follow the step at this post:

https://www.mummyluv.com/2019/01/Home-Page-blogspot-only-Shows-3-Posts-How-to-show-10-Posts.html

[image: p]